# Open local mbox mail archive with imap_open() in PHP

Tags: php, email, imap, mbox

I'm attempting to read an mbox email archive exported from another server locally, via file access, but for whatever reason everything I've tried fails. Is there some magical trick to parse a local file and access it with PHP's built-in IMAP functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use PHP's built-in IMAP functionality. Have you tried something like this:

```
function openLocal($file_path) {     
    $mbox = imap_open("$file_path",'','');
   if (!mbox) {
      $errorMsg = imap_last_error(); // do something with the error...
     return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```

And call this with the respective correct path:

```
openLocal('/home/email/temp/mailbox')
```

Comment: This comment needs more upvotes.  I've been searching for a solution for several hours.  This is the only one that has truly worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't find the accepted answer sufficient, though it did point me in the right direction.

PHP's IMAP library can be used to parse local `.mbox` files, such as the ones from Gmail exports.

Importantly, the path must be absolute, it cannot be relative to the current folder.

```php
$imap = imap_open($path_to_mbox, '', '');
```

You can then get retrieve information with [`imap`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) functions, such as the subject:

```php
$headers = imap_headerinfo($imap, 0); // Second parameter is the message number
$subject = $headers->subject;
```