# How imap_open() works with local file

Tags: php, imap

I am trying to read bounce emails using BMH. When trying the method of logging into mailbox using IMAP works fine. But when I try to use LocalFile method then I get the error mentioned later.

Below is the function I found here: [Open local mbox mail archive with imap_open() in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779217/open-local-mbox-mail-archive-with-imap-open-in-php)

```
function openLocal($file_path) 
{     
    $mbox = imap_open("$file_path",'','');
    if (!mbox) 
    {
         $errorMsg = imap_last_error(); // do something with the error...
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
         return true;
    }
  }
```

By using `$file_path = '/home/mailbox/';` I get the following error:

> Can't open /home/abhinav/mailbox: not a selectable mailbox

How can I fix this error?

Comment: BTW: why you quote variable `"$file_path"`?

Comment: sir i had tried without quotes, still not succeeded, well there was nothing specific i thought while quote, i don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: sir still getting same issue ::Can't open /home/mailbox: not a selectable mailbox

Comment: is it not possible to get access to email using localfile method

Comment: i had tried with possibilities mentioned in (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php )it but still no clue how to do it.